# How to keep first referrer by javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, referrer

I'm building website by Javascript React.
i want to keep my first referrer to know where people came from to my website.
(eg google.com/)
But when i redirect in my website referrer is changed from http://example.com to http://example.com/newpath.

When i use this.props.history.push('/path'), this can keep referrer, but  tag is changing my referrer.
Is there any way to keep referrer when first visit my website from google or any other domains?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the referrer-policy as ..

```
Referrer-Policy: origin
```

Or

```
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
```

Or

```
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

You can set them in your HTML

```
<meta name="referrer" content="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" />
```

Check the below link for better understanding of referrer-policies. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy